# PHP IF statement not working correctly on my website

Tags: php, if-statement

On my results page I have a while loop that is retrieving data from mysql and displaying it in a table. The table includes both home team and away team, half time score and full time score.

I've then got a bit of code that splits the home value and away value from full time score:

```
$value = $fulltime;
$apart = explode('-',$value);
```

I've then got an IF statement to firstly check if the home value is larger than the away value and then if the home id is the same as the winningid the user selected.

I've then done this for away win and if the game was a draw.

```
if($apart[0] > $apart[1]) {
    if($row["home_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
        $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
    }
} else if($apart[0] < $apart[1]) {
    if($row["away_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
        $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
    }
} else if($apart[0] == $apart[1]) {
    if(!$row["winningid"]) {
        $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
    }
} else { 
    $hometeamwin = "lose";
}

echo $hometeamwin;
```

what am I doing wrong in the IF statement?

Comment: well, what do the values in `$apart` contain?

Comment: You may want to take a different approach on formatting your code, this is very unreadable and illogical.

Comment: Which if statement? Use print_r on your variables to check that they contain what you expect. E.g. print_r($apart[0])

Comment: You should sort your code indentation out, might make it easier to debug as currently its confusing as to which if ends where..

Comment: What *is* wrong with it? I see code, but no indication that it's wrong or what is wrong.

Comment: I guess with the above code, home team will always win!

Comment: sorry guys, bit of a noob! $fulltime is say 4-0 so $apart[0] would be 4 and $apart[1] would be 0

Comment: What's supposed to happen if $apart[0] > $apart[1] and $row["home_id"] __!=__ $row["winningid"]?

Comment: I can't help but feel theres too much going on just to `echo` whether the game was a win or lose..

Comment: if $apart[0] > $apart[1] it is a homewin so then I check to see if the homeid matches the winningid I selected, so then you have won the bet

Comment: Oh OK so this is a betting result, that makes more sense. You didn't mention that. So what is actually the problem?

Comment: Sorry! And $hometeamwin should probably be something more general such as $win as it is not always home team that wins

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be called something like `$betResult`?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there's a forth option for numbers besides being larger, smaller or equal...?!

Comment: You have *if a > b else if a < b else if a == b*... and then another `else`. How is that last `else` ever going to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is you won't ever get to your fourth option and so therefore nobody will ever lose!

I do believe it should be this:

```
$hometeamwin = "lose";
if($apart[0] > $apart[1] && $row["home_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
    $hometeamwin = "Win";
}
else if($apart[0] < $apart[1] && $row["away_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
    $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
}
else if($apart[0] == $apart[1] && !$row["winningid"]) {
    $hometeamwin = "Win"; 
}
echo $hometeamwin;
```

You need to check whether the [ACTUAL WINNING TEAM]'s ID is equal (or not) to the [CHOSEN TEAM]'s ID **whilst** checking who won not **if** the condition is true.

It's not pretty but I think that's what you're going for.

Comment: that works perfectly thank you. Wouldn't it be great for the user if your bet never lost ha! Thanks for clearing this up :)

Comment: Do you think there would be a better way of doing it completely? As you say it's not pretty

Comment: @AndrewCharlton Well you could set your `$hometeamwin` to "lose" by default and then get rid of the final else for 1 (: - See my edit